# Looping with two variables from a vector

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a 30-vector, **x** where each element of **x** follows a standardised normal distribution.
So in Matlab,

I have:

```
for i=1:30;
x(i)=randn;
end;
```

Now I want to create 30*30=900 elements from  vector, **x** to make a 900-vector, **C** defined as follows:

[image]

I am unable to do the loop for two variables (k and l) properly. I have:

```
for k=1:30,l=1:30;
C(k,l)=(1/30)*symsum((x(i))*(x(i-abs(k-l))),1,30+abs(k-l));
end
```

It says '*??? Undefined function or method 'symsum' for input arguments of type
'double'.*'

I hope to gain from this a 900-vector, **C** which I will then rewrite as a matrix. The reason I have using two indices k and l instead of one is because I eventually want these indices to denote the (k,l)-entry of such a matrix so it is important that that my 900-vector will be in the form of **C** = [ row 1 row 2 row 3 ... row 30 ] so I can use the reshape tool i.e.

```
C'=reshape(C,30,30)
```

Could anyone help me with the code for the summation and getting such a 900 vector.

Comment: Where to start from ... for the first you can simply do `x=randn(1,30)`. Your second code block has no sense at all in Matlab ... as you cannot loop through 2 variables on the way you are trying to. Either you make both `k` and `l` depend on `i` and loop through `i`. What you tried makes not sense as you try to loop along `i` when that doesn't exist, hence the error. Then `'` has a meaning in Matlab `help ctranspose` and you should remove it from where you placed it. Furthermore, I don't think you need reshaping at all. I'd encourage you to read any Matlab intro.

Comment: `symsum` is for symbolic variables, not actual numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the short cuts, I'm really new to Matlab and I need to get this to work for a specific task. I am trying to Google and find a similar post but I don't quite know what I'm looking for. Is there any Matlab intro you can suggest? I will change the C' to D. 
A question, finding this 900-vector possible right?

Comment: You deleted your question on Mathematica stackexchange. I was going to post an answer. Shame on you! :)

Comment: I am about to repost it, I realsied I made some mistakes on the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to make this a bit efficient.

```
n = 30;
x = randn(n,1);

%# preassign C for speed
C = zeros(n); 

%# fill only one half of C, since it's symmetric
for k = 2:n
   for l = 1:k-1
      %# shift the x-vector by |k-l| and sum it up
      delta = k-l; %# k is always larger than l
      C(k,l) = sum( x(1:end-delta).*x(1+delta:end) );
   end
end

%# fill in the other half of C
C = C + C';

%# add the diagonal (where delta is 0, and thus each
%# element of x is multiplied with itself
C(1:n+1:end) = sum(x.^2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to have cracked it! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1523500: I have, on purpose, included a few vectorization tricks. I encourage you to go through the code and make sure that you understand what everything does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want a matrix C of 30x30 elements.
Given the formula that you provided I would do

```
x = randn(1,30)
C = zeros(30,30)
for k=1:30
    for l=1:30
        v = abs(k-l);
        for i =1:30-v
            C(k,l) = C(k,l) + x(i)*x(i+v);
        end
    end
end
```

if you actually need the vector you can obtain it from the matrix.

Comment: what about the missing `end` statements?

Comment: For some reason, the matrix that I get from this is the 0 matrix.

Comment: have you initialized the x vector? x = randn(1,30)

Comment: I did, but no worries! The answer below seems to have cracked it. I appreciate the help guys! Thank you!!